# get the ids of upper siblings using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im stuck at a functionality in jquery, the thing is, lets say i have 3 divs, now they all are siblings, so im standing at the third div i want the id of div 2 and div 1. All i want is to get the id of div2 and div3. i am using jquery to do that, but my current code is returning the id of div1 only.

```
<div class="main-div">
    <div class='div' id='1'>Div1</div>
    <div class='div' id='2'>Div2</div>
    <div class='div' id='3'>Div3</div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('#3').closest('[id]').find(".div").attr('id');
```

Comment: [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevall/) + [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). Sidenote: Don't use numeric IDs.

Comment: @Tushar.. i'm now using 
var tesst=$(this).prevAll().attr('id');
alert("The upper id: "+tesst);
but its saying the upper id: undefined

Comment: @Tushar..now im trying this
$(".has-drop").each(function(){
var tesst=$("#"+divIdIs).prevAll().attr('id');
alert("The upper id: "+tesst);
});
but the its returning me the id of the second div twice and no alert for first div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working example of what Tushar wants to say. 
[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/9mekgszr/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main-div">
  <div class='div' id='div1'>Div1</div>
  <div class='div' id='div2'>Div2</div>
  <div class='div selected' id='div3'>Div3</div>
  <div class='div' id='div4'>Div4</div>
</div>

<p><b>Previous Items</b></p>
<div class="prevIDs"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".selected").prevAll().each(function() {
  var divID =  $(this).attr('id');
  $('.prevIDs').append("<p>" +divID + "</p>");
});
```